# running ruby script with file pather args from a bash script

Tags: ruby, bash, scripting

I am using a bash script to launch a ruby script. 
this works very well if you are in the sir of the script but if you are not in that dir the script acts funny because it is not on the file path.

```
#!/bin/sh
jruby -Ilib script.rb $@
```

I added this to the script.

```
mypath=`realpath $0`

cd `dirname $mypath`/..
```

It makes the script run from any place I want. the problem is that its arguments do not get their relative path names changed.

I am using trollop for my input parsing.

My question is: How can I change the input of the path in the input so it will be the correct relative path when I push the args to the ruby script. 
I would be happy with a ruby fix to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses bash specifically. It assembles an array of the arguments, calling `realpath` for each.

```
#!/bin/bash
mypath=$(realpath $0)
args=()
for arg; do
  args+=( "$(realpath "$arg")" )
done
cd "$(dirname "$mypath")"/..

jruby -Ilib script.rb "${args[@]}"
```

I've liberally sprinkled double quotes throughout the script to handle files and paths that contain spaces.

Comment: Thanks, I think I can use your answer to just the args that paths into args for my ruby script and just pass the rest through.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it this way,

I found using environmental variables worked the best

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$EN_VARE"="" ]
then
 EN_VARE="."
fi

jruby -I$EN_VARE/lib $EN_VARE/lib/main_file.rb $@
```